# social auth django authentication Google

Tags: python, django

when authentication with google is completed the user is created in django.auth.user with all the correct fields but not logged in. It basically redirects to the redirect URL but doesn't log in the user.

I've tried several other projects including this one: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html

But same issue. Authentication and everything is all good. redirects back to url, creates django.auth.user but doesn't log the user in after redirecting.

I can go into django admin and login there but I would like it to automatically log the user in after the redirect from google.

Any help would be appreciated :)